# Android MVP implementation

Tags: android, design-patterns

i came across a few articles talking about the subject but i cannot understand how to apply MVP on my app code. is there any specific guidelines for a clean MVP implementation for android.

thank you

Comment: http://engineering.remind.com/android-code-that-scales/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout this link:
[Material movies](https://github.com/saulmm/Material-Movies)
[MVPAndroidBootstrap](https://github.com/richardradics/MVPAndroidBootstrap)
[Clean-Contacts](https://github.com/PaNaVTEC/Clean-Contacts)
[MvpCleanArchitecture](https://github.com/glomadrian/MvpCleanArchitecture)
[Android-CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture)
At this links you will find a lot of MVP implementations for android

## UPDATED:

[mosby](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby) - A Model-View-Presenter library for modern Android apps
[ThirtyInch](https://github.com/grandcentrix/ThirtyInch) - A new MVP library for Android
[Moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy) - Android MVP library without problems of lifecycle and boilerplate code

## UPDATED:

[Interesting-Android-repositories](https://github.com/AlexanderGarmash/Interesting-Android-repositories) - contains a lot MVP implementations for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Here on github 
https://github.com/saksham24/Android-Firebase-Mvp-Mvc-Mvvm-chat
 i made a repo containing 3 applications with same functionality but written in 3 different android patterns(Mvc, Mvp, Mvvm)

Understanding three different pattern is quite easy if we get a simple good example on them so i made a repo to contribute my knowledge to this developer community.
Also the repository is written using proper java guidelines and conventions(including naming and packages, modules) so people looking for such project can also view this repository.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created lightweight (with no overhead dependencies) MVP library in Kotlin. It also supports LiveData subscription between Presenter and Model under the hood.

Please find detailed "how-to" and sources here: https://github.com/smaslenko/instant-mvp