# What is the correct standard to implement MVP Design pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp, android-applicationinfo, android-mvp

What is the correct standard to implement MVP Design pattern in android application development. with proper example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android MVP implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940542/android-mvp-implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the good and clear example
https://github.com/antoniolg/androidmvp